# Use volume float vector velocity field for motion blur in Vector pass

Tags: volumetrics, motion-blur

I simulated a pyro sim in houdini that generated three vector field (vel.x, vel.y, vel.z) and then merged them into one velocity field that I exported to a vdb.
[image]

I applied a basic shader to the volume and enabled the vector render pass:
[image]

But for some reason, the Vector Blur node in the compositor does only blur the cube and not the volume. Do I have to pass the velocity field to the renderer? Is there something that I have to do in the shader?
[image]
Thank you for your help.